# Not able to unzip file from python script

Tags: python, automation, jython, python-2.5, jython-2.5

I'm using Python 2.5, and I can't upgrade python version.
Following is what I'm doing.

`call(['cp', zipFileName, zipPath])
 os.chdir(zipPath)
 call(['unzip', zipFileName])`

In above code I'm getting below error.
**unzip: cannot find or open gunzip gunzip.zip or gunzip.ZIP**

I did try below code. But still getting same error.

`for each in zip.namelist():
    if not each.endswith('/'):
      root, name = split(each)
      directory = norm(join(path, root))
      if not isdir(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
      file(join(directory, name), 'wb').write(zip.read(each))`

Please suggest the workaround if you know any.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a zip file or a gzip file?

Comment: Are you doing this to upgrade your Python version?

Comment: I have .zip file.                                                     No, I'm not doing this to upgrade Python version.

Comment: Why doesn't `call(['unzip',...])` work?  The error message means that the file `gunzip` (and gunzip.zip gunzip.ZIP) could not be found by `unzip`. `gunzip` is an odd name for a zipfile, but not wrong per se. Are you sure that the `cp` command succeeded?

Comment: Did you copy-paste that error message, or did you type it in? I would have expected this message: `unzip:  cannot find or open gunzip, gunzip.zip or gunzip.ZIP.`

Comment: @Robᵩ - Yes, that's exactly what I'm getting.

Comment: As a diagnostic measure, can you add `print ['unzip', zipFileName]` immediately before the call?

Comment: @mhawke - yes, cp command succeeded.

Comment: What is `call`? Please reduce your program to the smallest possible complete program that demonstrates the error. Copy-paste that small program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: Your code can't be generating the _same_ error as the `unzip` command. And what is `split()` and `norm()`?

Comment: @Robᵩ - print printed ['unzip', u'myzip.zip'] before that error. I'm not getting why small "u" printed before file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) module?

```
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zipFileName)
zf.extractall(path=zipPath)
zf.close()
```

This will extract all files from the zip file into the directory "zipPath".

Because your Python version is < 2.7.4 please read the warning regarding `extract()` and `extractall()` at https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall .

Comment: Sorry, extractall() is from 2.6 on.

Comment: Still no luck. This is what I'm getting **Unexpected error in Install:AttributeError("ZipFile instance has no attribute 'extract'",)**

Comment: Yep. You'll have to extract manually, or shell out can call unzip.

Comment: when I'm extracting manually following is what I'm getting. **Unexpected error in Install:AttributeError("'unicode' object has no attribute 'namelist'",)**

Comment: You are calling `namelist()` on a unicode object. You need to call `namelist()` on a `ZipFile` object. Add the actual code that you are using to the question.